# Me genera el error "PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function getKey() on string"

Tags: laravel-5, laravel

Al ejecutar mediante a consola `php artisan db:seed` me da el siguiente error PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getKey() on string

El error lo da precisamente con una funcion del Seeder ya que con otras funciones dio los resultados esperados.

Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Sluggable;
//use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\SluggableScopeHelpers;


class Categoria extends Model{
    use Sluggable; //SluggableScopeHelpers

     /**
      * Return the sluggable configuration array for this model.
      *
      * @return array
      */
    public function sluggable(){
        return [
            'slug' => [
                'source' => 'nombre'
            ]
        ];
    }

    protected $table = 'categorias';

    protected $fillable = ['nombre','slug','descripcion','color'];

    public $timestamps = false;

}
```

El ModelFactory

```
$factory->define(App\Categoria::class, function(Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return[
        'nombre' => $faker->randomElement(['Camisa de Jean','Camisa Oxford','Guayaberas', 'Guardacamisas','Camisa de vestir']), //Para elegir nombres random
        'descripcion' => $faker->paragraph, //Para escribir textos largos
        'color' => $faker->randomElement(['Azul','Verde','Rojo', 'Negra','Amarilla','Gris']), //Para elegir colores random
    ];
});
```

DatabaseSeeder

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run(){

        Model::unguard();

        //factory('App\User',10)->create();
        factory('App\Categoria',8)->create();
        //factory('App\Producto',20)->create();
        // $this->call(UserTableSeeder::class);

        Model::reguard();
    }
}
```

MIGRACIÓN DE LA TABLA CATEGORIAS

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCategoriasTable extends Migration{

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up(){

        Schema::create('categorias', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nombre');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->text('descripcion');
            $table->string('color');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down(){
        Schema::drop('categorias');
    }
}
```

**LAS OTRAS FUNCIONES EN EL MODELFACTORY NO SÉ ESTAN EJECUTANDO POR ESO NO LAS MUESTRO EN MIS CODIGOS**

Comment: Modifica tu pregunta y coloca la migración de la tabla para ver como la creas.

Comment: Listo, los cambios fueron realizados.

Comment: intenta con: factory(App\Categoria::class, 8)->create();

Comment: Igual, amigo, el mismo error. Me da este error precisamente 
PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function getKey() on string in C:\xampp\htdocs\tienda_online\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection.php on line 82

Comment: para que es: "Sluggable"?

Comment: ya investigue, un generador de urls

Comment: Es lo que me hace generar la opción de los "link" mas limpia por decirlo de alguna manera. Ejemplo el post se llama "Laravel me suelta un error" el sluggable genera "Laravel-me-suelta-un-error"

Comment: exactamente eso te iba a decir, el problema que tienes es con "Sluggable" por que envié "strings" en el "modelfactory" y lo registra tranquilamente.

Comment: te fallo hermano, no se como se maneja esos "slugs"

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53779/discussion-between-luis-morales-and-pablo-contreras).

Comment: ¿Tienes la última versión de tu framework? Según se dice aquí: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/12853 , se trata de un bug que fue corregido a partir de la versión 5.3.30

Comment: No, estoy usando la 5.1, amigo.

Comment: @LuisMorales entonces es posible que sea ese el problema. Considera actualizar a la última versión. Saludos.

Comment: Si, justo estoy en eso.

Answer (score 1):

Luego de tanto luchar CREO que llegue a una posible solución, no es definitiva pero puede dar cabida por si alguien le ocurre el mismo error...

En el archivo `config/sluggable.php` se puede apreciar que al rededor de la linea 65 nos sale Lo siguiente

```
/**
 * Enforce uniqueness of slugs?  Defaults to true.
 * If a generated slug already exists, an incremental numeric
 * value will be appended to the end until a unique slug is found.  e.g.:
 *
 *     my-slug
 *     my-slug-1
 *     my-slug-2
 */

'unique' => true,
```

Según esto quiere decir que el valor de nuestro slug será unico y por eso yo no podía crear muchos campos porque el orden aleatorio conseguía el mismo y daba por sentada el orden aleatorio.